# Built-in symbols which are more close to the root/core of Wolfram Language

Tags: evaluation, core-language, built-in-symbols

Seeing the vast scope of science covered by the Wolfram Language (WL) and the large amount of built-in symbols (functions), I am curious to know which built-in symbols are more close to the root of WL, i.e., they are wired deeper in the kernel and are less easily bypassed by tricks.

For example, when assigning `UpValues` the assignment tag should be at level no deeper than 2. If we make an assignment like

```
Clear[f,g,tag,fg]
tag/:f[g[tag]]:=fg[tag]
```

a warning message is displaced as

> TagSetDelayed::tagpos: "Tag tag in f[g[tag]] is too deep for an assigned rule to be found."

and the evaluation returns `$Failed`, because the `tag` is at level 3.

However, there are some built-in symbols which are not restricted by the level-2-requirement:

```
list = {HoldPattern, ReleaseHold, Unevaluated, Evaluate,
        Refresh, Activate, IgnoringInactive};
Map[(tag /: f[#[tag]] := #) &, list];
```

In this code the `tag` is at level 3, however all assignments can be made successfully without generating error message.

Even at level 4 there is no error message for some combinations:

```
Map[(tag /: f[#[[1]]@#[[2]]@tag] := #) &, Tuples[list, 2]]
```

For example, this assignment is successful,

```
tag /: f[Evaluate@HoldPattern@tag] := tag
```

It appears that the built-in symbols in `list` are not considered as normal wrapper. Some of these symbols are also less easily bypassed by using tricks like assigning `UpValues`, for instance,

```
tag /: HoldPattern[tag[x_]] := x;
HoldPattern[tag[_]]
```

which still returns

> HoldPattern[tag[_]]

It is reasonable that, out of the thousands of built-in symbols, some of them are more fundamental and the others are built basing on the fundamental ones. Can we find out these fundamental symbols? So we can at least know a bit more about the mystery behind the veil.

Comment: Everything listed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/B.8.html) that's still in the current version is most likely part of the core.

Comment: Left hand side of definition is to some extent evaluated, so from your list `ReleaseHold`, `Unevaluated`, `Evaluate`, `Refresh` and `Activate` when applied to `tag` inside `f`, simply evaluate to `tag`. Symbols like `HoldPattern` or `IgnoringInactive` are also not "more fundamental" they just have special meaning in pattern matching and so are not taken into account when calculating how deep is `tag` inside pattern.

Comment: One can try to find such symbols with special meaning in pattern matching by testing whether expressions involving those symbols match themselves. Evaluation of ``Quiet@Select[Names["System`*"], 
  With[{heldExpressions = 
      ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
       Function[sym, {HoldComplete[sym[x]], HoldComplete[sym[x, y]]}, 
        HoldAllComplete]]}, ! 
     MatchQ[heldExpressions, heldExpressions]] &]`` gives list of 20 such symbols.

Comment: @ jkuczm, I see what you mean. When making assignments (with six operators: `Set`, `SetDelayed`, `TagSet`, `TagSetDelayed`, `UpSet` and `UpSetDelayed`), the head then all arguments of lhs are completely evaluated, but the applying of any existing rule for the last step to completely evaluate the partly evaluated lhs (using first `UpValues`, then `DownValues` and finally `SubValues`) is avoided. Thank you for your comments, now my understanding of the evaluation process is strengthened.