# Except @ OptionsPattern[] affects OptionValue

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, options, optional-arguments

#### The background

This example works as expected, small function with a special case rule:

```
foo // ClearAll    
foo // Options = {"bar" -> 1};    

foo[x_, y : Except[_Rule], patt : OptionsPattern[]
] := {x, y, OptionValue["bar"]};

foo[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := foo[x, "def", opts]
```

```
foo["xx", "bar" -> 3]
```

> ```
> {"xx", "def", 3}
> ```

`Except[_Rule]` is needed because I don't want `f["xx", "bar"->1]` to go directly to the first definition and treat the option as  `y`.

#### The problem

However, originally I used:

```
...
foo[x_, y : Except[OptionsPattern[]], patt : OptionsPattern[] ]:=...
...
```

but then

```
foo // ClearAll
foo // Options = {"bar" -> 1};

foo[x_, y : Except[OptionsPattern[]], patt : OptionsPattern[]
] := {x,  y, OptionValue["bar"]};

foo[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := foo[x, "def", opts]

foo["xx", "bar" -> 3]
```

> ```
> {"xx", "def", 1}
> ```

#### The question

Why wasn't the "bar" passed down?

I don't have time to investigate and will proceed with the workaround but would like to understand that as nothing obvious comes to my mind now.

Comment: What do you expect from something like `foo["xx", MaxRecursion -> 3]`, with non-`foo` option? (I expected an error but didn't get one.)  The problem seems to be that `patt` is not passed to `OptionValue`, so another workaround is to use the full form `OptionValue[foo, patt, "bar"]`.  Perhaps it's confused by the two occurrences of `OptionsPattern[]`?

Comment: Related: [(1567)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1567/121)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, error would be expected.

Comment: I've hit this block before, I know, when doing meta-programming. My go-to now is to use a construct like `Except[_?OptionQ]` which seems to be reasonably solid and less-restrictive than `Except[_Rule]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 That's exactly the solution I first proposed (see link above) but I think a case can be made for `Shortest` being superior, which I learned about later.

Answer (score 10):

Recall that [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionValue.html) is a ["magic" symbol](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121981/121) with nonstandard behavior.  The expression `OptionValue["bar"]` "by magic" gets its value without it being explicitly passed one, working with its "magic" brother [`OptionsPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html) in a not-entirely-transparent way.  I think it attaches to the first `OptionsPattern[]` object <s>which is not used in the final matching with `"bar" -> 3`</s>.

I don't yet have a clear idea of what is happening but I can give other examples of weird behavior.

#### exhibit A

```
ClearAll[foo]
Options[foo] = {"bar" -> 1};

foo[
  first : Except[OptionsPattern[]],
  second : OptionsPattern[]
] := {{first}, {second}}

foo["arg", "bar" -> 3]
```

> ```
> {{"bar" -> 3}, {}}
> ```

- `"arg"` disappears entirely.  Theoretically for the rule on `foo` to apply `"arg"` should be attached to either `first` or `second` patterns, but instead it vanishes as though attached to a third pattern expression
- `"bar" -> 3` is attached to `first`, implying that it *matches* `Except[OptionsPattern[]]`, despite the fact that `MatchQ["bar" -> 3, Except[OptionsPattern[foo]]]` returns `False`

#### exhibit B

Let's see what happens if we name the first appearance of `OptionsPattern[]` itself.

```
ClearAll[foo]
Options[foo] = {"bar" -> 1};

foo[
  first : Except[op1 : OptionsPattern[]], 
  second : OptionsPattern[]
] := {{first}, {second}, {op1}}

foo["arg", "bar" -> 3]
```

> ```
> {{}, {}, {"bar" -> 3}}
> ```

- Once again `"arg"` goes missing, but this time `"bar" -> 3` is *not* attached to `first` as it was before, leaving both `first` and `second` empty.  Instead it is attached (only) to `op1`.

#### a note about `Except`

[`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html) at times causes strange behavior.  For example, I believe from an earlier question I cannot at the moment find:

```
Cases[{1, 0, 2, 0, 3}, Except[x : 0] :> x]
```

> ```
> {Removed["$Variable"][1], Removed["$Variable"][1], Removed["$Variable"][1]}
> ```

Combining this somewhat peculiar pattern construct with the "magic" of `OptionsPattern` may simply be a bad idea at this time, unless and until this edge case is specifically addressed by the developers.

---

#### version differences

In version 10.1 from your second block of code I get:

```
In[6]:= foo["xx", "bar" -> 3]
```

> During evaluation of In[6]:= OptionValue::rep: def is not a valid replacement rule. >>
>
> ```
> Out[6]= {"xx", "bar" -> 3, 1}
> ```

Did I enter it wrong or has behavior changed?

Comment: It changed, already v10.4 returns `{"xx", "def", 1}`.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for highlighting this weird behavior.  I'll be looking at this more.  Need coffee.

Comment: @Kuba Do any of the examples in my post behave differently in 10.4?

Comment: Yes, both, and 10.4 output is the same as 11.1.1's. That is: A) `{{"arg"}, {"bar" -> 3}}` and B) `{{"arg"}, {"bar" -> 3}, {}}`

Comment: @Kuba Well that's good, I think.  Do you get the desired output if you use `foo[x_, y : Except[OptionsPattern[]], patt : OptionsPattern[]
] := {x,  y, OptionValue[foo, patt, "bar"]};` ?