# Why can't I inject expressions in Compile using (only) With

Tags: evaluation, compile, scoping

Generally speaking, `With` can be used to inject into arbitrarily held expressions, for example:

```
With[{args = 2},
  Hold @ Hold @ HoldComplete[args]
]
(* Out[1]= Hold[Hold[HoldComplete[2]]] *)
Attributes @ foo = HoldAll;
With[{args = {{x, _Real}}},
  foo[args, x + 2]
]
(* Out[2]= foo[{{x, _Real}}, x + 2] *)
```

However, trying to do the same exact thing to inject inside `Compile` does not work:

```
With[{args = {{x, _Real}}},
  Hold @ Compile[args, x + 2]
]
(* Hold[Compile[args, x + 2]] *)
```

Also, the only relevant attribute of `Compile` is `HoldAll`, which as shown in the first examples is not really a problem for this kind of injection.
Does this mean that `Compile` follows some special evaluation rules (even though it's not listed among the [magic symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121981/27539))?

Using a Trott-Strzebonski-like trick, like shown for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29318/27539), does work:

```
With[{args = {{x, _Real}}},
  Hold @ Compile[args, x + 2] /; True
][[1]]
(* Hold[Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x + 2]] *)
```

An extract from Leonid's explanation in the above linked answer explains why adding the `Condition` works:

> The basic idea is to exploit the semantics of rules with local
>   variables shared between the body of `With` and the condition, but
>   within the context of local rules. Since the condition is `True`, it
>   forced the `eval` variable to be evaluated inside the declaration part
>   of `With` (...)

This explanation does not however explain why the use of `Compile` in particular makes a difference, why does it prevent `With` from injecting into it, and why can we avoid this constraint adding a `Condition`?

---

Some more examples of functions showing or not showing this kind of behaviour:

```
With[{args = x}, Hold@Compile[args, 2]]
With[{args = x}, Hold@Function[args, 2]]
With[{args = x}, Hold@Module[args, 2]]
With[{args = x}, Hold@With[args, 2]]
With[{args = x}, Hold@Block[args, 2]]
(*
  Out[1]= Hold[Compile[args, 2]]
  Out[2]= Hold[Function[args, 2]]
  Out[3]= Hold[Module[x, 2]]
  Out[4]= Hold[With[x, 2]]
  Out[5]= Hold[Block[x, 2]]
*)
```

Also, in at least some cases it matters whether there is a second argument:

```
With[{args = x}, Hold @ Compile[args]]
With[{args = x}, Hold @ Function[args]]
(* Out[1]= Hold[Compile[args]] *)
(* Out[2]= Hold[x &] *)
```

Comment: For the last case `With[{args = x}, Hold @ Function[args]]`, my guess would be that a function with a single arg is treated as a slot-based pure function, which is not considered a scoping construct in the context of protection of local variables, since it does not use named variables (it uses slots instead). Which is why such protection is not there in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compile is considered a scoping construct by the outer `With`, and its bindings are protected. This will work:

```
With[{args = {{x, _Real}}}, Hold[Compile @@ Hold[args, x + 2]]]
```

or this (if you don't want to keep `Apply` in code):

```
Unevaluated[ 
  With[{args = {{x, _Real}}}, Hold[Compile[args, x + 2]]]
] /. Compile -> $compile /. $compile -> Compile
```

One relevant link is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/81). If you don't want to care about inner scoping constructs, use replacement rules instead of `With` - the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/81) at your service:

```
Hold @ Compile[args, x + 2] /. Unevaluated[args ->   {{x, _Real}}]
```

For the Trott-Strzebonski part, it works because there, `With` is a secondary device serving essentially replacement rules. There, you could directly use [`RuleCondition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/81) instead of `With`. So my point is, for Trott-Strzebonski trick, the essential part is that one uses replacement rules. And rules don't care about inner scoping constructs.

It has been noticed in comments and in the edit of the original question, that not all scoping constructs are treated in the same way, and in particular for `Function` (with named arguments) and `Compile`, the entire declaration is protected, while for `With` and `Module` the protection happens on the level of individual variables (in terms of name collisions).

Comment: Another illustration: `With[{args = x}, Hold@Function[args, x + 2]]`

Comment: Leonid, wouldn't `With[{args = {{x, _Real}}}, Compile @@@ Hold[Hold[args, x + 2]]]` be a better substitution for this?

Comment: Interesting. I have a few questions though: 1) why is `Compile` considered a scoping construct? And is there a list of functions that are considered scoping constructs by `With`? It doesn't show in `Attributes` or such. 2)  running my second example with `With` instead of `Compile` works as expected (as in, it replaces `args`), doesn't this contradict your argument about inner scoping constructs?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks, I added that and some more examples in the question

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is a possibility, yes - there are surely many. The second one I gave in the answer is somewhat different though, which is why I thought it made sense to provide it.

Comment: @glS 1) `Compile` binds variables (in this case, declares their types), so it has to protect those variables (they can be defined outside, and that should not affect `Compile`) - which is why it is considered a scoping construct. 2) I would guess that the variable - protecting mechanism treats `Compile` somewhat differently from other scoping constructs. For those, it looks at conflicts of individual scoped variables, while here, it protects the full declaration. Consider this, for an example or protection in action: `With[{args = {{x, _Real}}}, Hold@With[{args = {1, 2, 3}}, args + 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure but cannot we use `Evaluate` in this case?

```
With[{args = {{x, _Real}}},
Hold@Compile[Evaluate@args, x + 2]
]
(* Hold[Compile[Evaluate[{{x, _Real}}], x + 2]] *)
```

Comment: `Evaluate` is the wrong tool here, and it only "works" because the presence of `Evaluate` hides `Compile` from outer `With` (it does no longer recognize `Compile` as a scoping construct). But this would bite you later, for example if `x` has been globally defined.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks i see. But as long as no global variable is defined the approach should work. I get your point, it is better to use `Unevaluated` on the whole expression and make the replacements inside

Comment: `Evaluate` only works one level deep, and even there only for heads which are not `HoldAllComplete`. In this case, the expression is too deep for `Evaluate` to have any effect at the time when external `With` evaluates. But later, it will force `Compile` to evaluate its first argument, which is not desirable for a scoping construct.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin to better understand your last point do you mind giving an example that i can check, especially the case when the head has an attribute of `HoldAllComplete`

Comment: Just try `HoldComplete[Evaluate[1+1]]` for a start. Also, read the chapter 7 of David Wagner's book (chapter on evaluation), he explains this very clearly.