# Including literals into compiled C code

Tags: compile, meta-programming

I have a function that I want to Compile into C for speed. Inside this function is a certain long expression called x, which has been computed earlier in a Mathematica session. However, if you call x naively inside the code, then you are referring to an "external variable" and so ordinary Wolfram Language code is used instead.

See below. The second version is 100 times faster because it got properly compiled into C. How can I include x in the code without literally copying-and-pasting a huge expression, which muddies up my notebook?

```
x = Sin[i^2]*Cos[i] (* A fairly long complicated expression *);
compiledsum1 = Compile[{{NumPoints, _Integer}}, 
   Block[
    {i, sum = 0.0},
    For[i = 0, i < NumPoints, i++, sum += x;];
    sum
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
compiledsum2 = Compile[{{NumPoints, _Integer}}, 
   Block[
    {i, sum = 0.0},
    For[i = 0, i < NumPoints, i++, sum += Sin[i^2]*Cos[i];];
    sum
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Timings:

```
compiledsum1[100000] // Timing
{0.841049, 223.296}
compiledsum2[100000] // Timing
0.006448, 223.296
```

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153064/4999

Comment: Externals are inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`, see `CompilationOptions` in `Compile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is your friend:

```
x = Sin[i^2]*Cos[i] (*A fairly long complicated expression*);
compiledsumtest1 = 
  Hold@Compile[{{NumPoints, _Integer}}, 
      Block[{i, sum = 0.0}, For[i = 0, i < NumPoints, i++, sum += x;];
       sum], CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. OwnValues@x // ReleaseHold;
```

---

Of course the solution above isn't the simplest for your specific problem. [Henrik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255583/1871) and [I.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255577/including-literals-into-compiled-c-code/255580#comment637161_255577) have already shown two simpler solutions, I'd like to add one more based on pure function:

```
x = Sin[i^2]*Cos[i] (*A fairly long complicated expression*);
compiledsumtest2 = 
  Compile[{{NumPoints, _Integer}}, 
     Block[{i, sum = 0.0}, For[i = 0, i < NumPoints, i++, sum += #;];
      sum], CompilationTarget -> "C"] &@x;
```

But do remember the pattern-matching-based method is more general, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145936/1871)'s an example.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me to the best reference to understand all of this wizardry? The documentation is quite tricky for me to properly grasp.

Comment: @BruceBartlett You may have a look at [Leonid Shifrin's book](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5060/1871), that's where I first learned about `@`, `OwnValues`, etc. These days [Stephen Wolfram's book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) is a good choice, too.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6):

Even easier with `With`.

```
 compiledsum3 = With[{x = x},
  Compile[{{NumPoints, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{i, sum = 0.0}, 
    For[i = 0, i < NumPoints, i++, sum += x;]; 
    sum
   ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"]
 ]
```

(This is certainly a duplicate, but I have no time to look it up...)